# Ok i have a task, i need to make something like this: obj.function().function().function() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object

It's my code

```
 const Steps= {
                ItemValue: 0,
                GetNumber() {
                    return this.ItemValue;
                },
                Step(){
                    return this.getNumber()++;
                },
                StepBack() {
                    return this.getNumber()--;
                },
                NoStep(){
                    return this.getNumber();
                }
            }
```

I need to make something like this:
It's a question's code

```
const obj = {...Steps};
obj.Step()
       .Step()
       .StepBack()
       .Step()
       .StepBack()
       .NoStep();
```

In c# it's easy, but here i cann't understend, where is the problem.
You can just give me advise, how google it or decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To chain methods on object you need to return that object in each method so that next method you call is called on the object. Also this `this.getNumber()++` will result in `SyntaxError`.

```js
const Steps = {
  ItemValue: 0,
  GetStep() {
    return this.ItemValue;
  },
  Step() {
    this.ItemValue++;
    return this;
  },
  StepBack() {
    this.ItemValue--;
    return this;
  },
  NoStep() {
    return this;
  }
}

const obj = {
  ...Steps
};

obj.Step()
  .Step()
  .StepBack()
  .Step()
  .StepBack()
  .NoStep()

console.log(obj.GetStep())
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea of using it with using a class. Each method returns the instance.

```js
class myCode {
  constructor(val) {
    this.value = val || 0;
  }

  add(val) {
    console.log("add", this.value, "+", val);
    this.value += val;
    return this;
  }

  subtract(val) {
    console.log("subtract", this.value, "-", val);
    this.value -= val;
    return this;
  }

  double() {
    console.log("double", this.value, "* 2");
    this.value *= 2;
    return this;
  }

  get val() {
    console.log("val");
    return this.value;
  }
}

const myCodeInstance = new myCode(10)
myCodeInstance
  .add(2)
  .subtract(4)
  .double();
  
console.log(myCodeInstance.val);
```